# Using a %ROWTYPE in a WHERE IN clause

Tags: oracle, plsql, where-clause, database-trigger, rowtype

I am trying to write a trigger that deletes certain rows from my table TRIGGERREF1 when I am updating another table TRIGGERTEST1. 
Here is the code:

```
create or replace TRIGGER "DELETEBYUPDATE_TRIGGERTEST1" BEFORE UPDATE ON TRIGGERTEST1
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    referencedItems TRIGGERREF1%rowtype;
BEGIN 
    SELECT * INTO referencedItems FROM TRIGGERREF1 WHERE OWNER = :New.ID;
    EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN RETURN;
    DELETE FROM TRIGGERREF1 a WHERE a.OWNER IN referencedItems;
END;
```

The line

```
DELETE FROM TRIGGERREF1 a WHERE a.OWNER IN referencedItems;
```

Does not compile because, apparently you can't do a **WHERE IN %ROWTYPE** condition.

Is there a way to make this work or do I need to solve my problem without the use of %ROWTYPE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply delete directly?

```
create or replace TRIGGER "DELETEBYUPDATE_TRIGGERTEST1" BEFORE UPDATE ON TRIGGERTEST1
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
BEGIN 
    DELETE FROM TRIGGERREF1 a WHERE a.OWNER = :New.ID;
END;
```

Because, when there is no row matching your WHERE condition just nothing is done.

Answer (score 2):

That would probably be something like

```
DELETE FROM TRIGGERREF1 a WHERE a.OWNER = referencedItems.owner;
                                        ^                ^^^^^^^
                                       this              this
```

i.e. you'd reference a column within the `rereferncedItems`.

Comment: I'm guessing that `referencedItems` means the SELECT may return multiple records. Another reason why I like @Radagast81 solution.

Comment: From my point of view, because of `WHERE OWNER = :New.ID`, I'd say that ID's are *unique* so this `select` will return a single row. It wouldn't work otherwise, if there were two or more rows for the same ID (too-many-rows, right?). But yes - I agree; *less is more*, just like you said.

Comment: Hmmm, I would say it is quite likely that an OWNER can own more than one ITEM. Although we can't be sure because the OP hasn't provided sample data or a model.

Comment: ReferencedItems can indeed hold more than one item, thus referencing a column didn't work, however, @Radagast81 solution was all I needed to make it work.

Comment: OK, thank you for the feedback. I'm glad you fixed it.